# Copy Stream and ReadToEndAsync()

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have a custom stream reader derived from System.IO.Stream which does not support position and Seek to move the header to beginning to read a stream twice.

I need to copy a stream to another variable before I do a ReadToEndAsync(). I would later use the copy stream to read again from beginning.

Is there a way I can do this ?

```
var stream = customStream;

customStream.ReadToEndAsync();

var st = new StreamReader(stream);

st.ReadToEndAsync();
```

not getting any data, since head is at the end of stream from the previous command.

I have tried 
`Stream.Position = 0;` //Not working because its not supported by the custom Stream Reader

`stream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` //Not working because its not supported by the custom Stream Reader

Comment: I'd probably work with memorystream (Or write it to a filestream if memory constraints are an issue): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx